# Query database to grab data per unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with the following information (Don't mind the CreatedDates not matching, this is a testing database table):

[image]

I want to be able to create a query to `Intents` and the respective `Transcript` based on the `ContactId` (which there are multiple for one user).

As of right now I was able to accomplish pulling out the `Intents` by user (distinct) with the following:

```
SELECT distinct [ContactId],[Intents] = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' ,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Intent))
           FROM ACCOUNT_DATA b
           WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM ACCOUNT_DATA a
GROUP BY ContactId;
```

My desired output would be something like this:

Query => Select all users from the Database (distinct) and return Intents (Distinct) + Transcript data and count of the intents. So like:

```
d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4
RescheudleApt (4) : Reschuedle Appointment, Ok, what date?, Ok, what date?,Ok, what date?
ConfirmAppt (2): Confirm my appointment, ok your appointment has been confirmed
```

So on and so forth for each `ContactId` in the table, how would I go about this and am I on the right track?

I know that this would be formatted in different alias tables such as `ContactId`, `Count`, `Transcript`.

Comment: do you really need to concatenate `Intent` column? doing so will require that you concatenate the `Transcript` column as well. I suggest that you do not concatenate and do any manipulation on your frontend application.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    ContactId,
    Intent + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(Intent)) + ')' as Intents, 
    [Transcript] = STUFF((SELECT ' ,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Transcript))
                          FROM ACCOUNT_DATA b
                          WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
                            AND b.Intent = a.Intent
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
    ACCOUNT_DATA a
GROUP BY 
    ContactId, Intent
ORDER BY 
    ContactId
```

Here's a [demo](https://rextester.com/WBXPRU93906)

or if you want to concatenate `Intent` and `Transcript`

```
SELECT 
    ContactId,
    Intent + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(Intent)) + ') : ' +
        STUFF((SELECT ' ,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Transcript))
               FROM ACCOUNT_DATA b
               WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
                 AND b.Intent = a.Intent
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS "Intent + Transcript"
FROM
    ACCOUNT_DATA a
GROUP BY 
    ContactId, Intent
ORDER BY 
    ContactId
```

**Edit: Final Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ContactId, [Transcript]=STUFF((SELECT '; ' + IntentTranscript
           FROM (
                    SELECT a.ContactId,
                        a.Intent + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(a.Intent)) + ') : ' +
                        STUFF((SELECT ' ,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Transcript))
                               FROM ACCOUNT_DATA b
                               WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
                               AND b.Intent = a.Intent
                              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS "IntentTranscript"
                    FROM ACCOUNT_DATA a
                    GROUP BY a.ContactId, a.Intent
                ) c
           WHERE c.ContactId = INNER_ACCOUNT_DATA.ContactId
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.ContactId,
        a.Intent + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(a.Intent)) + ') : ' +
        STUFF((SELECT ' ,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Transcript))
               FROM ACCOUNT_DATA b
               WHERE b.ContactId = a.ContactId
               AND b.Intent = a.Intent
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS "IntentTranscript"
    FROM ACCOUNT_DATA a
    GROUP BY a.ContactId, a.Intent
) AS INNER_ACCOUNT_DATA
ORDER BY ContactId
```

Here's a [demo](https://rextester.com/BVFD66375)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, this is quite the query. I don’t know if I would have been able to come to this conclusion by myself haha. Would it be possible to pull count out into a different column?

Comment: with this query no. You always need to check the number of rows that will be generated when writing query, separating count to different column will result in more rows than the current result, which sql wont support. else you need to do the same thing and concatenate those for the same `ContactId` but that will be confusing as the result wont show what that count is for.