# Putting string with multiple data items into object

Tags: c#, sql

Imagine I have some data like this that is returned from a SQL query:

```
ContactId                                           Transcript
60b0e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a21f1c0f1                [Options-13] : Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,I can do this that and the other ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome!
d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4                [ConfirmApt-2] : Confirm my appointment ,ok your appointment has been confirmed [RescheudleApt-4] : Reschuedle Appointment ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t
re80e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a54f1c0f1                [ConfirmAppt-1] : This is another thing
```

I then put this data into a `List<Tuple<string, string>>()` So that each entry looks like:

```
Item1:   60b0e926-2f3a-458d-91f7-fe4a21f1c0f1
Item2: [Options-13] : Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,Give me options ,I can do this that and the other ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome! ,Awesome!


Item1:d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4  
Item2: [ConfirmApt-2] : Confirm my appointment ,ok your appointment has been confirmed$ [RescheudleApt-4] : Reschuedle Appointment ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t
```

..and so on

I am trying to create an object that will hold all this data, in the correct format. The format that I'm going for essentially is linking my intents

> Options, ConfirmAppt, RescheduleAppt

with their respective transcripts, which is between the two tags. As an example the second item on the list is:

```
d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4                [ConfirmApt-2] : Confirm my appointment ,ok your appointment has been confirmed [RescheudleApt-4] : Reschuedle Appointment ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t ,Ok, what date?t
```

### What I would like to see is:

```
Key: d463d996-78cc-428e-8a76-e4875e1c8ff4
Intent: ConfirmApt
Count: 2
Transcript:
[0] Confirm my appointment
[1]ok your appointment has been confirmed

Intent: RescheudleApt
Count: 4
Transcript:
[0]Reschuedle Appointment
[1]Ok, what date?t
[2]k, what date?t
[3]Ok, what date?t
```

and so on for the other items in my list.

I have attempted to start to do this but hit a wall when I started to try to link the the intents with the transcript.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        var intentList = new List<IntentPerUserModel>();
        foreach (var user in intents)
        {
            var intentItem = new IntentPerUserModel();

            intentItem.ContactId = user.Item1;

            var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(user.Item2, pattern);
            var intentNames = new List<string>();
            var intentCount = new List<string>();

            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                intentNames.Add(match.Groups[1].Value.Split('-')[0]);
                intentCount.Add(match.Groups[1].Value.Split('-')[1]);
            }

            var listOfTranscriptItems = new List<string>();



            intentItem.Intents.Add(new Tuple<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>>(intentNames, intentCount, listOfTranscriptItems));
            intentList.Add(intentItem);
```

Can someone explain to me how to accomplish this?

Comment: The SQL Query returns exactly what you're seeing, I need to do some data manipulation and put this into an object so it's easier for me to pass this up to my front end and then do what I want with it there. I'm really not sure what you would accomplish from a `DataTable` that you can't accomplish from a `Tuple`. The data from the query complies the data in this way.

Comment: Did you write the SQL query or is it coming from a 3rd party source? Because the sample data shows 3 different ConactId's but yet you seem to be associating all of the Transcript data with one Contact Id

Comment: @RyanWilson it does... see the string example he put up (scroll right)... I think he's having trouble parsing the transcript lines -- I see no way of knowing which line would be the first, second, third, etc. since there's no line delimiter.

Comment: They are delimited by `:` . If you see in my example.

Comment: I posed this SQL data question in another thread, this was what an answer was and I'm trying to work with that. If you have a better idea of how to query this let me know! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693759/query-database-to-grab-data-per-unique-id/56695736#comment99969264_56695736

Comment: A more simplified approach would be to create a `List<T>` of your class type.
Do a simple `SELECT` statement from your database and `ORDER By` the `ContactID` and fill a `DataTable`.
Iterate the rows of the `Datatable` and create new `objects` when a new `ContactID` is encountered, else add to your `Lists` of `Intent` and `Transcripts` respectively. Then add object of your custom class to the `List<T> `of your custom class

Comment: What would be your structure when the class considering that intents and transcripts need to be linked and there is an unknown amount of intents. Would you put  them in to `List<string>` and then try to join them after or?

Comment: @Frank I would make a class called Intent which contains a List of Transcripts. Then add a List of Intents to your Contact class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank, to use my simplified comment, structure your classes as such:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string ID { get; }
    public IList<Intent> Intents { get; }

    public Contact(string id) { ID = id; Intents = new List<Intent>(); }
}

public class Intent
{
    public IList<string> Transcripts { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Intent(string name) { Name = name; Transcripts = new List<string>(); }
}
```

To then populate everything, pretend we have already acquired a DataTable via your query the SELECT should be ORDERED BY ContactID, Intent:

```
//Create List<T> of type Contact
IList<Contact> contactInfo = new List<Contact>();
//Temp var for storing the contact to add to list
Contact contact = null;
//Temp var for storing current Intent object
Intent intent = null;

foreach(DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows)
{
         //If we are at a new contact, create the new contact object
         if(contact == null || contact.ID != row["ContactId"].ToString())
         {
              if(contact != null)
                 contactInfo.Add(contact);

              if(contactInfo.Contacts.Where(x => x.ID == row["ContactId"].ToString()).Count() > 0)
              {
                  //set contact to existing contact
                  contact = contactInfo.Contacts.Where(x => x.ID == row["ContactId"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
              }
              else
              {
                   //set contact to a new Contact Object with the given contact id
                  contact = new Contact(row["ContactId"].ToString());
              }

         }


         //IF we are at a new Intent create it and add to List of Intents of current contact
         if(intent == null || intent.Name != row["Intent"].ToString()
         {
             //Per your comment Frank
             //Check to see if we have an Intent in our contact.Intents list with the current Intent name
             if(contact.Intents.Where(x => x.Name == row["Intent"].ToString()).Count() > 0)
             {
                 intent = contact.Intents.Where(x => x.Name == row["Intent"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
             }
             else
             {
                 intent = new Intent(row["Intent"].ToString());
                 contact.Intents.Add(intent);
             }

         }

         contact.Intents[contact.Intents.Count - 1].Transcripts.Add(row["Transcript"].ToString());   


}

contactInfo.Add(contact); //Add the final contact to the list
```

Comment: `   public Intent(string name) { Name = name; Transcripts = new List<Transcript>(); }` what is `List<Transcript>` in this case? Just a list of string?

Comment: @Frank Typo on my part, updated to set it to new `List<string>` as well as add the final contact object to the `IList<Contact>`

Comment: `contact.Intents[contact.Intents.Count - 1].Add(row["Transcript"].ToString());` what are you trying to do here? You're grabbing an item via the index but then trying to add to the list?

Comment: @Frank add the transcript value to the List of transcripts for the current Intent

Comment: Yea, I see that but you can't use an `Add()` method on an item that you're grabbing via the index and you can't add a string to the intents list .. so that's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Frank Once again , typo I forgot to add the Property name on the end, fixed. Also, if the item grabbed via Index implements `IList` you can call `.Add()`

Comment: Gotcha, ok I understand what you were trying to do now. The problem I see in your logic is that if the intents aren't all grouped together in the query.. meaning that the list of intents is like "Options, Options, Confirm., Options' ContactInfo at the end will break it out into 3 contact objects. 1 for the two "Options", 1 for the "Confirm" and then another for the last "Option"

Comment: @Frank there are two solutions, 1. You can make your Query ORDER BY ContactId, Intent which I added as an edit to my answer, or 2. you can search your List for an Intent with the current rows Intent name and if it exists just add to it's list of transcripts, else create new Intent object.

Comment: @Frank I updated my answer for your specific use case about the Intents not being ordered in the query, you could do the same kind of check in contact if you were concerned about the contacts not being ordered. And you are quite welcome. I was always told to try to use `KISS` (Keep It Simple Stupid), and sometimes it's easy to over complicate things when working between SQL and .Net code, to me it just made more sense to simplify the query and use the logic in .Net to transform it.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is to return the same structure as object you have defined in your c# code you and define a stored procedure that returns user difined type by output parameter.